# How to navigate from child components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to navigate to different components using a sidebar, but It seems I'm doing something wrong.

**App.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import Appbar from "./Components/Appbar";
import Table from "./Components/Table";
import InfoInput from "./Components/InfoInput";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Appbar />
          <Drawer anchor="right" open={true}>
            <div>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/tables/">tables</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/Info/">info</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </Drawer>
          <header className="App-header">
            <h1>Main page</h1>
          </header>
          <Route exact path="/" component={null} />
          <Route path="/tables/" component={Table} />
          <Route path="/info/" component={InfoInput} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is a screenshot. I want to navigate from main page to other pages (like Tablet or InfoInput) when I click the links in sidebar.

[image]

Comment: Always have `<Route>` component direct child of `<Router>`. Here there is `<div>` in between. So just take `<Route>` out of `div`

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. @MeetZaveri

Comment: Take `<Route>` registration up/before the navigation code.

Comment: Great to know that it worked